# JavaScript Map Two arrays into in Multidimensional Object

Tags: javascript

I need to take two arrays of separate arrays of objects and map it to a new array of objects.  I just can't seem to figure it out in ES6. I know I need to map through the first array and reduce on the second array but I am getting lost.  I included a snippet, which fails on the reduce at `Combined: acc[i].Combined.push(name.SId),`

two arrays:

Array 1

```
[
    {
      "BId": 1,
      "Name": "Test1",
    },
    {
      "BId": 2,
      "Name": "Test2",
    }
]
```

Array 2

```
[
    {
      "Id": 1,
      "BId": 1,
      "SId": 2,
      "GId": 1
    },
    {
      "Id": 2,
      "BId": 1,
      "SId": 2,
      "GId": 2
    },
    {
      "Id": 3,
      "BId": 1,
      "SId": 3,
      "GId": 1
    },
    {
      "Id": 1,
      "BId": 2,
      "SId": 2,
      "GId": 1
    },
    {
      "Id": 2,
      "BId": 2,
      "SId": 2,
      "GId": 2
    },
    {
      "Id": 3,
      "BId": 2,
      "SId": 3,
      "GId": 1
    },
    {
      "Id": 3,
      "BId": 2,
      "SId": 3,
      "GId": 4
    },
]
```

result:

```
[
    {
      "BId": 1,
      "Name": Test1,
      "Combined": [{SId:2, GIds[1,2]}, {SId:3, GIds[1]}]
    }
    {
      "BId": 2,
      "Name": Test2,
      "Combined": [{SId:2, GIds[1,2]}, {SId:3, GIds[1,4]}]
    }
]
```

```js
const array1 = [
        {"BId": 1,
          "Name": "Test1",
        },
        {
          "BId": 2,
          "Name": "Test2",
        }
    ];
    
const array2 = [
        {
          "Id": 1,
          "BId": 1,
          "SId": 2,
    "GId": 1
        },
        {
          "Id": 2,
          "BId": 1,
          "SId": 2,
    "GId": 2
        },
        {
          "Id": 3,
          "BId": 1,
          "SId": 3,
    "GId": 1
        },
  {
          "Id": 1,
          "BId": 2,
          "SId": 2,
    "GId": 1
        },
        {
          "Id": 2,
          "BId": 2,
          "SId": 2,
    "GId": 2
        },
        {
          "Id": 3,
          "BId": 2,
          "SId": 3,
    "GId": 1
        },
        {
          "Id": 3,
          "BId": 2,
          "SId": 3,
    "GId": 4
        },
    ];
    
    
     const all = array1.map(a1 => {
      combined = array2
        .filter(a2 => a2.BId === a1.BId)
        .reduce((acc, name, i) => {

          const obj = {
            BId: name.BId,
            Name: name.Name,
            Combined: acc[i].Combined.push(name.SId),
          };
          acc.push(obj);

          return acc;
        }, []);
      return bv;
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope it helps...

```js
const array1 = [
        {"BId": 1,
          "Name": "Test1",
        },
        {
          "BId": 2,
          "Name": "Test2",
        }
    ];
    
const array2 = [
        {
          "Id": 1,
          "BId": 1,
          "SId": 2,
    "GId": 1
        },
        {
          "Id": 2,
          "BId": 1,
          "SId": 2,
    "GId": 2
        },
        {
          "Id": 3,
          "BId": 1,
          "SId": 3,
    "GId": 1
        },
  {
          "Id": 1,
          "BId": 2,
          "SId": 2,
    "GId": 1
        },
        {
          "Id": 2,
          "BId": 2,
          "SId": 2,
    "GId": 2
        },
        {
          "Id": 3,
          "BId": 2,
          "SId": 3,
    "GId": 1
        },
        {
          "Id": 3,
          "BId": 2,
          "SId": 3,
    "GId": 4
        },
    ];
            
const all = array1.map(arr => {
  let combined = []
  array2
  .filter(e => arr.BId === e.BId)
  .forEach(e => {
    const {GId, SId} = e
    combined.push({GId, SId})
  })
  combined = combined.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  const {GId, SId} = cur
  const idx = acc.findIndex(e => e.SId === SId)
  if (idx !== -1) {acc[idx].GId.push(GId)}
  else {acc.push({SId, GId: [GId]})}
  return acc
  },[])
  return {...arr, combined}
 });
 
 console.log(all)
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, but the result is not combined how it was stated, this is a lot closer than I got tho! GIds need to be combined within the combined object as well (thats the tricky part)

Comment: Ok, do I understand correctly that you want to aggregate based on SIds?

Comment: exactly, they group on SIds! :)

Comment: sweet.  I am going to see if I can clean that up into ES6, but thats an aswer.  Cheers mate.

Comment: @Harleyz You can't get more ES6 than this :D

Comment: very close to a true statement --> https://codeburst.io/javascript-map-vs-foreach-f38111822c0f

Answer (score 1):

```js
let a_array = [
    {
      "BId": 1,
      "Name": "Test1",
    },
    {
      "BId": 2,
      "Name": "Test2",
    }
];

let b_array = [
    {
      "Id": 1,
      "BId": 1,
      "SId": 2,
      "GId": 1
    },
    {
      "Id": 2,
      "BId": 1,
      "SId": 2,
      "GId": 2
    },
    {
      "Id": 3,
      "BId": 1,
      "SId": 3,
      "GId": 1
    },
    {
      "Id": 1,
      "BId": 2,
      "SId": 2,
      "GId": 1
    },
    {
      "Id": 2,
      "BId": 2,
      "SId": 2,
      "GId": 2
    },
    {
      "Id": 3,
      "BId": 2,
      "SId": 3,
      "GId": 1
    },
    {
      "Id": 3,
      "BId": 2,
      "SId": 3,
      "GId": 4
    },
];

a_array.map( (a_object) => {
 if(!a_object.Combined) a_object.Combined = [];

 return b_array.map((b_object) => {

  if(a_object.BId === b_object.BId) {

   let c = a_object.Combined.filter( (_c) => ( _c.SId === b_object.SId ) );

   if(c && c[0]) {
    if(!c[0].GIds.includes(b_object.GId)) c[0].GIds.push(b_object.GId);

   } else {
    a_object.Combined.push({"SId": b_object.SId, "GIds": [b_object.GId]})

   }

   return a_object;

  }

 })

} )

console.log(a_array);
```

Comment: This feels like a bizarre use of `map`.  Using `map` to update a value is strange enough, but using it to *occasionally* update it (depending upon some criteria) seems scary!

Comment: @ScottSauyet - i think filter would be okay here in place of the if(a_object.BId === b_object.BId).  I will include the final result probably by end of day.

Answer (score 1):

I might write something like this:

```js
const combine = (arr1, arr2) => arr1 .map (({BId, ...rest}) => ({
  BId, 
  ...rest,
  Combined: Object .entries (
      arr2 .filter (({BId: b}) => b == BId)
           .map (({SId, GId}) => ({SId, GId}))
           .reduce ((a, {SId, GId}) => ({...a, [SId]: [...(a [SId] || []), GId]}), {})
  ) .map (([sid, GIds]) => ({SId: Number (sid), GIds}))
}))


const arr1 = [{BId: 1, Name: "Test1"}, {BId: 2, Name: "Test2"}]
const arr2 = [{Id: 1, BId: 1, SId: 2, GId: 1}, {Id: 2, BId: 1, SId: 2, GId: 2}, {Id: 3, BId: 1, SId: 3, GId: 1}, {Id: 1, BId: 2, SId: 2, GId: 1}, {Id: 2, BId: 2, SId: 2, GId: 2}, {Id: 3, BId: 2, SId: 3, GId: 1}, {Id: 3, BId: 2, SId: 3, GId: 4}]


console .log (combine (arr1, arr2))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {min-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

I think it's fairly straightforward.  The `BId` and `Name` properties are taken from the first array (using `...rest` to include other properties if they are there.)  And we calculate `Combined` like this:

- The `filter` line finds the matching entries.
- The first `map` line extracts the two properties we care about.
- The `reduce` line groups them into a structure like `{"2": [1, 2], "3": [1]}`.
- We call `Object.entries` on that to get back `[["2", [1, 2]], ["3", [1]]]`.
- And then the second `map` line turns that into `[{SId: 2, GIds: [1, 2]}, {SId: 3, GIds: [1]})`.  Because we used the `SId` as a key, it was turned into a String.  We use `Number` here to convert it back.